# How to bring a text at the center of a square box in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a design below which I am trying to replicate in HTML/CSS:

[image]

The above design has 2 boxes with text "Icon" at the center of each.

At this moment, I am able to get this in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/902wtjtv/3/show/) with text "icon" not at the center of a box.

The HTML and CSS codes which I have used to get that box and the text "icon" are:

HTML code:

```
<div class="squares">
      <div class="icon1">
         <p>Icon</p>
      </div>
      <div class="icon2">
         <p>Icon</p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

CSS code:

```
.icon1,
.icon2 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #F5F8FA;
}

.icon1 {
    margin-right: 10%;
    border-style: ridge;
}

.icon2 {
    margin-left: 10%;
    border-style: ridge;
}
```

I think I have to put `display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;` to make icon text come at the center of a box but unfortunately its not working for some reasons:

```
 .icon1 {
        margin-right: 10%;
        border-style: ridge;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }   

 .icon2 {
        margin-left: 10%;
        border-style: ridge;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        }
```

Comment: How's this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pWbXdJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a contradiction in there: You set `display` to `inline-block` for both, then in the following rules you set it to `flex`, which overwrites the inline-block setting, so the squares won't be displayed next ot each other.

Apply `display: flex` to the parent (`.squares`) and erase the inline-block setting:

```css
.squares {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.icon1,
.icon2 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #F5F8FA;
}


 .icon1 {
        margin-right: 10%;
        border-style: ridge;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }   

 .icon2 {
        border-style: ridge;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        }
```

```html
<div class="squares">
      <div class="icon1">
         <p>Icon</p>
      </div>
      <div class="icon2">
         <p>Icon</p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Although it worked but I want to bring the boxes at the center as you can see in the design. Just wondering what changes in the CSS code I have to make to bring them at the center.

Comment: At this moment, the boxes are going towards the left.

Comment: Just add `justify-content: center;` to `.squares` (I edited my answer accodingly)

Answer (score 1):

you can use flex property on parent div like this, you'll get the desired outcome

```
.squares {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
text-align: center; /* horizontal align */
display: table-cell; /*display as table cell to make possible vertical align */
vertical-align: middle;
```

Because you know height probably easy to make one more div inside with padding-top: 80px for example